# Import Parameters from files in a subfolder

Tags: python, parameter-passing, python-import

There must be a better solution than the abomination i have cooked up.

I have a variety of devices that run on slightly different hardware. I communicate with said devices and test their functionality which is influenced by their hardware. So I have a subfolder with a file for each device with different parameters.

Mainfolder
|--> Subfolder ( with 20 Devices files.py  )

For example different upper and lower boundries for acceptable voltage levels. But every Devices runs the same test function but overrides the boundries with the subfolder file.
My current approach is that at the start of the test the device is selected and the device file is added via:

```
sys.path.append(str(os.getcwd()) + "\Devices")
if(Device==xyz):
     from Device_xyz import *
```

I have two main issues here:

1. The import is dirty since its in a subfolder. It works but Vs Code gives me warning that the file does not exist, until he actually tries to load it. Probably because of the weird os.path adding.
2. VS Code is strongly confused by this. It works but every parameter from the imported file is underlined as not found until the code executes.

Any kinda soul with some input how to do this more professional would be much appreciated!

Comment: Put settings in a single json or similar structured file. When running the function read the settings for the specific device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `__init__.py` to make it a package and then your imports should work as expected without that hack. Here's the link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: I have done that too ! But with or without the __init__.py file I get the same issue. Still thanks for the input, I will read that part of the doc again, maybe I did something wrong with the init file.

Comment: I really doubt that, you need to make sure that every folder in your entire hierarchy has an `__init__.py`. Since your hack works I assumed you are starting python from your main folder, otherwise you need to add it to your python path.

Comment: Also, if there are any `*.pyc` files or other temporary files, please delete them...